# how can i manage bool query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to get result of bool query in elasticsearch for example: 
content should contain 'red' and 'blue' or 'yellow' not 'purple' 
( ('red' AND 'blue') OR 'yellow' ) NOT 'purple' 
how can i create correct bool query in elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct `bool` query for your constraint would be the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "red"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "blue"
          }
        }
      ],     
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "yellow"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "color": "purple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```